# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, исключения, null

```java
package javax.swing;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.security.AccessController;
import javax.accessibility.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.RootPaneUI;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import sun.awt.AWTAccessor;
import sun.security.action.GetBooleanAction;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JRootPane extends JComponent implements Accessible {
    private static final String uiClassID = "RootPaneUI";
    public static final int COLOR_CHOOSER_DIALOG = 5;
    public static final int FILE_CHOOSER_DIALOG = 6;
    public static final int QUESTION_DIALOG = 7;
    public static final int WARNING_DIALOG = 8;

    private int windowDecorationStyle;

    protected JMenuBar menuBar;

    /**
     * The content pane.
     */
    protected Container contentPane;

    /**
     * The layered pane that manages the menu bar and content pane.
     */
    protected JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    protected Component glassPane;

    protected JButton defaultButton;

    boolean useTrueDoubleBuffering = true;

    static {
        LOG_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING =
                AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetBooleanAction(
                        "swing.logDoubleBufferingDisable"));
        IGNORE_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING =
                AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetBooleanAction(
                        "swing.ignoreDoubleBufferingDisable"));
    }

    public JRootPane() {
        setGlassPane(createGlassPane());
        setLayeredPane(createLayeredPane());
        setContentPane(createContentPane());
        setLayout(createRootLayout());
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        updateUI();
    }

    public void setDoubleBuffered(boolean aFlag) {
        if (isDoubleBuffered() != aFlag) {
            super.setDoubleBuffered(aFlag);
            RepaintManager.currentManager(this).doubleBufferingChanged(this);
        }
    }

    public int getWindowDecorationStyle() {
        return windowDecorationStyle;
    }

    public void setWindowDecorationStyle(int windowDecorationStyle) {
        if (windowDecorationStyle < 0 ||
                windowDecorationStyle > WARNING_DIALOG) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid decoration style");
        }
        int oldWindowDecorationStyle = getWindowDecorationStyle();
        this.windowDecorationStyle = windowDecorationStyle;
        firePropertyChange("windowDecorationStyle",
                oldWindowDecorationStyle,
                windowDecorationStyle);
    }

    public RootPaneUI getUI() {
        return (RootPaneUI) ui;
    }

    public void setUI(RootPaneUI ui) {
        super.setUI(ui);
    }

    public void updateUI() {
        setUI((RootPaneUI) UIManager.getUI(this));
    }

    public String getUIClassID() {
        return uiClassID;
    }

    protected JLayeredPane createLayeredPane() {
        JLayeredPane p = new JLayeredPane();
        p.setName(this.getName() + ".layeredPane");
        return p;
    }

    protected Container createContentPane() {
        JComponent c = new JPanel();
        c.setName(this.getName() + ".contentPane");
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout() {

            public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
                if (constraints == null) {
                    constraints = BorderLayout.CENTER;
                }
                super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
            }
        });
        return c;
    }

    protected Component createGlassPane() {
        JComponent c = new JPanel();
        c.setName(this.getName() + ".glassPane");
        c.setVisible(false);
        ((JPanel) c).setOpaque(false);
        return c;
    }

    protected LayoutManager createRootLayout() {
        return new RootLayout();
    }

    public void setJMenuBar(JMenuBar menu) {
        if (menuBar != null && menuBar.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(menuBar);
        menuBar = menu;

        if (menuBar != null)
            layeredPane.add(menuBar, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setMenuBar(JMenuBar menu) {
        if (menuBar != null && menuBar.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(menuBar);
        menuBar = menu;

        if (menuBar != null)
            layeredPane.add(menuBar, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }

    public JMenuBar getJMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public JMenuBar getMenuBar() {
        return menuBar;
    }

    public void setContentPane(Container content) {
        if (content == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("contentPane cannot be set to null.");
        if (contentPane != null && contentPane.getParent() == layeredPane)
            layeredPane.remove(contentPane);
        contentPane = content;

        layeredPane.add(contentPane, JLayeredPane.FRAME_CONTENT_LAYER);
    }

    public Container getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }

    public void setLayeredPane(JLayeredPane layered) {
        if (layered == null)
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("layeredPane cannot be set to null.");
        if (layeredPane != null && layeredPane.getParent() == this)
            this.remove(layeredPane);
        layeredPane = layered;

        this.add(layeredPane, -1);
    }

    public JLayeredPane getLayeredPane() {
        return layeredPane;
    }

    public void setGlassPane(Component glass) {
        if (glass == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("glassPane cannot be set to null.");
        }

        AWTAccessor.getComponentAccessor().setMixingCutoutShape(glass,
                new Rectangle());

        boolean visible = false;
        if (glassPane != null && glassPane.getParent() == this) {
            this.remove(glassPane);
            visible = glassPane.isVisible();
        }

        glass.setVisible(visible);
        glassPane = glass;
        this.add(glassPane, 0);
        if (visible) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public Component getGlassPane() {
        return glassPane;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValidateRoot() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return !glassPane.isVisible();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    public void removeNotify() {
        super.removeNotify();
    }

    public void setDefaultButton(JButton defaultButton) {
        JButton oldDefault = this.defaultButton;

        if (oldDefault != defaultButton) {
            this.defaultButton = defaultButton;

            if (oldDefault != null) {
                oldDefault.repaint();
            }
            if (defaultButton != null) {
                defaultButton.repaint();
            }
        }
        firePropertyChange("defaultButton", oldDefault, defaultButton);
    }

    public JButton getDefaultButton() {
        return defaultButton;
    }

    final void setUseTrueDoubleBuffering(boolean useTrueDoubleBuffering) {
        this.useTrueDoubleBuffering = useTrueDoubleBuffering;
    }

    final boolean getUseTrueDoubleBuffering() {
        return useTrueDoubleBuffering;
    }

    final void disableTrueDoubleBuffering() {
        if (useTrueDoubleBuffering) {
            if (!IGNORE_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING) {
                if (LOG_DISABLE_TRUE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING) {
                    System.out.println("Disabling true double buffering for " +
                            this);
                    Thread.dumpStack();
                }
                useTrueDoubleBuffering = false;
                RepaintManager.currentManager(this).
                        doubleBufferingChanged(this);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    static class DefaultAction extends AbstractAction {
        JButton owner;
        JRootPane root;
        boolean press;

        DefaultAction(JRootPane root, boolean press) {
            this.root = root;
            this.press = press;
        }

        public void setOwner(JButton owner) {
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (owner != null && SwingUtilities.getRootPane(owner) == root) {
                ButtonModel model = owner.getModel();
                if (press) {
                    model.setArmed(true);
                    model.setPressed(true);
                } else {
                    model.setPressed(false);
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return owner.getModel().isEnabled();
        }
    }

    protected void addImpl(Component comp, Object constraints, int index) {
        super.addImpl(comp, constraints, index);

        if (glassPane != null
                && glassPane.getParent() == this
                && getComponent(0) != glassPane) {
            add(glassPane, 0);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    protected class RootLayout implements LayoutManager2, Serializable {
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();

            if (contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getPreferredSize();
            } else {
                rd = parent.getSize();
            }
            if (menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getPreferredSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.max(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                    rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }

        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();
            if (contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getMinimumSize();
            } else {
                rd = parent.getSize();
            }
            if (menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getMinimumSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.max(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                    rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }

        public Dimension maximumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            Dimension rd, mbd;
            Insets i = getInsets();
            if (menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                mbd = menuBar.getMaximumSize();
            } else {
                mbd = new Dimension(0, 0);
            }
            if (contentPane != null) {
                rd = contentPane.getMaximumSize();
            } else {
                // This is silly, but should stop an overflow error
                rd = new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE - i.top - i.bottom - mbd.height - 1);
            }
            return new Dimension(Math.min(rd.width, mbd.width) + i.left + i.right,
                    rd.height + mbd.height + i.top + i.bottom);
        }

        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            Rectangle b = parent.getBounds();
            Insets i = getInsets();
            int contentY = 0;
            int w = b.width - i.right - i.left;
            int h = b.height - i.top - i.bottom;

            if (layeredPane != null) {
                layeredPane.setBounds(i.left, i.top, w, h);
            }
            if (glassPane != null) {
                glassPane.setBounds(i.left, i.top, w, h);
            }
            // Note: This is laying out the children in the layeredPane,
            // technically, these are not our children.
            if (menuBar != null && menuBar.isVisible()) {
                Dimension mbd = menuBar.getPreferredSize();
                menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, w, mbd.height);
                contentY += mbd.height;
            }
            if (contentPane != null) {
                contentPane.setBounds(0, contentY, w, h - contentY);
            }
        }

        public void addLayoutComponent(String name, Component comp) {
        }

        public void removeLayoutComponent(Component comp) {
        }

        public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
        }

        public float getLayoutAlignmentX(Container target) {
            return 0.0f;
        }

        public float getLayoutAlignmentY(Container target) {
            return 0.0f;
        }

        public void invalidateLayout(Container target) {
        }
    }

    protected String paramString() {
        return super.paramString();
    }

    /////////////////
    // Accessibility support
    ////////////////
    public AccessibleContext getAccessibleContext() {
        if (accessibleContext == null) {
            accessibleContext = new AccessibleJRootPane();
        }
        return accessibleContext;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    protected class AccessibleJRootPane extends AccessibleJComponent {
        public AccessibleRole getAccessibleRole() {
            return AccessibleRole.ROOT_PANE;
        }

        public int getAccessibleChildrenCount() {
            return super.getAccessibleChildrenCount();
        }

        public Accessible getAccessibleChild(int i) {
            return super.getAccessibleChild(i);
        }
    } // inner class AccessibleJRootPane
}
```

[image: Появляется следующая ошибка. СПАСИТЕ! Я полный нуб , облазила весь интернет , не могу найти решения.]

Появляется следующая ошибка. СПАСИТЕ! Я полный нуб , облазила весь интернет , не могу найти решения.

Comment: в 21 строке класса AuthorizationGUI у вас происходит операция, в результате которой объекту contentPanel присваевается(читается из него) null.

Comment: Нельзя присваивать `contentPanel` значение `nul`l. Исследуй строку 21.

Answer (score 0):

посмотри тут может поможет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844177/intellij-swing-gui-not-compiling-because-of-gradle

Там проблема между IntelliJ GUI Designer и Gradle

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

<sub>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос Intellij (Swing) GUI not compiling because of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57776137/14823438) от участника [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4030720).</sub>

---

В настройках IDEA нужно указать:

- **`Automatically import`**
- **`Build and run using` ⇒ `IntelliJ`**
- **`Run tests using` ⇒ `IntelliJ`**
- **`Gradle JVM` ⇒ `Project JDK`**

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ]